# Set the name of Zip archive using ZipArchive class

Tags: php

The code I currently have, attached below, successfully writes files into an archive and initiates downloading of the file but the filename is a random alphanumeric string. A few examples of these file titles are:

- IfTO57y8.zip
- PFuuPgMD.zip
- KUgWDc0T.zip

How can I set the name of the Zip folder to something more user-friendly?

```
function start_brochures_download( $brochures ) {
$confirmation = "Your download should begin shortly. \r\n";
$error = "Files not set \r\n";

$files = $brochures;

if( $files ) {

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    $current_time = time();

    $file_name = "Brochures-".$current_time;

    $file_folder = wp_upload_dir();
    $dir = $file_folder['path'];
    $zip_file = $dir.'/'.$file_name.'.zip';

    $zip->open( $zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE );

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if( !empty($file) ){
            # download file
            $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

            #add it to the zip
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
        }
    }

    $zip->close();

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_file));
    // header("Location: $zip_file");
    readfile($zip_file);

} else {
    echo $error;
}
}
```

Comment: is there a `form` being used anywhere in this process?

Comment: Yes, the files are chosen by checkboxes. The website uses Gravity Forms so there is a separate function for retrieving checkbox values.

Comment: another field specifically for the name would seem the easiest method then

Comment: Seems you are setting the name with `$file_name` ... so its curious why it downloads with gibberish instead. Doesn't even include the `.zip` extension?

Comment: I don't want the user to set the name of the Zip, I want the name to be static, e.g: "Brochures.zip"

Comment: @IncredibleHat the .zip extension is included on the archive but when the archive is extracted, the folder is names like the gibberish above.

Comment: This is curious behavior, as I use ZipArchive a LOT for admin tool log dump downloads etc (built dynamically), and not once come across this. Got me curious! I wish I had an answer though :(

Comment: Wait a minute... you have `filename="'.$zip_name.'"` for the header change. But, that variable is not defined. Maybe try setting it to `filename="'.$file_name.'.zip"`

Comment: @IncredibleHat Well spotted!! That's fixed it, thanks!!